# How to avoid multipart/form-data with XMLHTTPRequest and FormData

Tags: aws-lambda, xmlhttprequest, form-data

I'm trying to setup an html form, the form action is an aws lambda function.
When I submit the form via plain html, all is well. However, when I'm sending the form via XMLHTTPRequest + FormData the lambda function breaks.

Looking at the lambda logs it seems that when using the plain html form send, the form is encoded in the request body as straight forward query string `('name=Johnny&email=john%40bon.com' etc)` which my lambda function can parse.
However, when using XMLHTTPRequest+FormData to send the form, the form is encoded in using a different format which I believe (not sure) is called multipart/form-data (has these WebKitFormBoundaryXXX additions).

Is there a way to make XMLHTTPRequest+FormData send the form in the same format as is used when sending the form via plain html. Alternatively, how to do parse this multipart/form-data format in aws lambda python.

````
    const form = document.querySelector('#my-form-id')
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      // disable default action
      event.preventDefault()

      // configure a request
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open('POST', 'www.myurl.com/submit')

      // prepare form data
      let data = new FormData(form)

      // set headers
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

      // send request
      xhr.send(data)

      // listen for `load` event
      xhr.onload = () => {
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
      }
      })```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make XMLHTTPRequest+FormData send the form in the same format as is used when sending the form via plain html.

Well. It does… for a value of plain HTML with `enctype='multipart/form-data'`.

If you want to send application/x-www-form-urlencoded data then `FormData` is the wrong tool for the job.

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead.

You can initialise it with a FormData object.

```js
const data = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(document.querySelector('form')));
console.log(`${data}`);
```

```html
<form>
    <input name=foo value=bar>
    <input name=x value=y>
</form>
```

Note that `XMLHttpRequest` can infer the `Content-Type` header when you pass a `URLSearchParams` or `FormData` object to `send()` so don't set it manually. That is just a waste of time and an opportunity to introduce errors.

Answer (score 0):

Quentin's solution works. Here's the corrected code:

````
    form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
      // disable default action
      event.preventDefault()

      // configure a request
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
      xhr.open('POST', 'www.myurl.com/submit')


      // send request
      xhr.send(new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form)))

      // listen for `load` event
      xhr.onload = () => {
        console.log(xhr.responseText)
      }
})```
````